# Horizontal and Vertical scrollbar are glued to columns whenever the page loads in AngularJs UI grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Whenever the page loads, both of the horizontal and vertical scrollbar floats on top of UI grid. I am populating the grids in 2 different places. 1st place it is looking the way it is supposed to be but not on the other place.

**Screenshot of the working grid**
[image]

**Screenshot of non-working grid**
[image]

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Looks like the second grid is empty. Hence, its height is `0`.

Comment: But when i open it in developer mode, the scrollbar moves to its original position

Comment: You should add more information and your code otherwise it is difficult to help you.

Comment: please check the minrows...or it may be dealt with $interval or Parent div height